# Using LiveData in Spinner

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

I am newer in android. I use  room database, AndroidViewModel, and LiveDate in my project. There is a model "Receipt" in my project, I have an activity with name "AddReceiptActivity" that there is a Spinner in this activity to display and select Place. There is another model for Place that store places. How to display Place table's(model) values in Spinner for select.
this is my Place entity

```
@Entity
public class Place implements Serializable {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private Integer placeId;
private String placeName;

public Place(String placeName, Boolean removed) {
    this.placeName = placeName;
    this.removed = removed;
}

public Integer getPlaceId() {
    return placeId;
}

public void setPlaceId(Integer placeId) {
    this.placeId = placeId;
}

public String getPlaceName() {
    return placeName;
}

public void setPlaceName(String placeName) {
    this.placeName = placeName;
}
}
```

and this is my ViewModel

```
public class AddReceiptViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
DataBase database;

public AddReceiptViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    database = DataBase.getDataBase(this.getApplication());
}

public void addRceipt(final Receipt receipt) {
    new AddAsyncTask(database).execute(receipt);
}

private static class AddAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Receipt, Void, Void> {
    DataBase db;

    public AddAsyncTask(DataBase db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Receipt... receipts) {
        db.receiptDao().add(receipts[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Now I don't  now how to Set data From my model to Spinner in Activity.

```
     AddReceiptViewModel addReceiptViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AddReceiptViewModel.class);

     Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerLoadingPlace);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a list which is store places list.

Let's say `List<Place> places = new ArrayList<>();`

first of all, you should ovverride toString method for Place model for put the name of each place in spinner.

```
@ovverride
public String toString(){
 return this.placeName;
}
```

In your activity class, you will put the list into spinner with this function;

```
public void setList(){
ArrayAdapter<Place> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<Place>(getApplicationContext(),  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, places);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And finally, you can get selected item;

```
Place selectedPlace = (Place) spinner.getSelectedItem();
```